# How to conditionally "pass through" a gesture from a UIButton to a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a long, horizontal, narrow `UIScrollView` containing several buttons side-by-side.  When a user drags a button vertically, a specific method is triggered (via a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`), and the scrollview doesn't scroll (even if his/her drag begins to go left or right).  This is all good.

When a user drags horizontally anywhere on the scrollview, including directly on a button, the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` ignores the effect and the scrollview should scroll.  It's the last effect I'm having trouble with: when the user horizontally drags directly on a button, the scrollview doesn't scroll.  How can I "pass through" that horizontal gesture to the scrollview?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your buttons' UIPanGestureRecognizer's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return (otherGestureRecognizer == _scrollView.panGestureRecognizer);
}
```

Comment: That's _exactly_ what I needed.  Thanks!  All of my angle-calculating functions are no longer necessary.  I'll just disable scrolling at the start of the vertical-button-drag and enable afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

On UIScrollView you can override

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
```

Subclass UIScrollView (or UITableView) and return `YES`. It will cancel any touch from subviews when scrolling starts.

Answer (score 0):

Give a thought to UILongPressGestureRecognizer. This might help you: [Combine longpress gesture and drag gesture together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272333/combine-longpress-gesture-and-drag-gesture-together#9272417)