# UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer Combined

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm implementing both `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` should start on a drag and the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` should start on a long press

Unfortunately when `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is called with a drag also the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is being called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method does exactly what I looked for:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

See: [Combining a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with a UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492200/combining-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-with-a-uipangesturerecognizer)