# how to fail UILongPressGestureRecognizer for UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

In my view, i added long press gesture and pan gesture as below

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fitToView:)];
    [longPressRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 5.0f;
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    [panRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPressRecognizer];
```

and their gesture handlers are given below:

```
-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [recognizer translationInView:self.imgView ];

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _firstX = [self.imgView center].x;
        _firstY = [self.imgView center].y;
    } 

    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, translatedPoint.x , translatedPoint.y );

    self.imgView.transform = newTransform;

}

-(void)fitToView:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }

}
```

long press is meant to restore the image. But when i moves the image long press gesture delegate also calls and restoring all the changes i have done. i used `[panRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPressRecognizer];` to fail long press recognizer. But it doesnt happens. I also tried delegate method
**gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:**. But it didnt work

Comment: remove  [longPressRecognizer setDelegate:self]; and  panRecognizer.delegate = self; and see is it working?

Comment: try the other way...
[longPressRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRecognizer];

Comment: from your code pangesture will not recive any event when Longpressgesture is active. Hope your need is just reverse. So change to [longPressRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRecognizer]

Comment: i tried it.but it didnt work

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing delegate function

```
gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

and return YES

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this related answer [Combining a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with a UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492200/combining-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-with-a-uipangesturerecognizer) from **@annie**?

You can do this solely with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.