# ios - How to select multiple cells in a single gesture?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Looking to select multiple UITableviewCells by long pressing and running my finger down to subsequent cells and selecting those also,

Anyone know of a way of doing so with UILongPressGestureRecognizer

(think Spotify touch preview)

Comment: Do not vote a question down because you have an issue with title phrasing, i do however appreciate the edit request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could get tricky, but maybe I can point you down the right path.

First, you need a reliable way to start a long press and keep tracking the pan. You will probably need to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in combination with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, applied to the view itself (not the cells). When the pan recognizer has activated, you'll need to disable the `UITableView` gesture recognizers so they don't interfere. All of this will require `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

See this post for some more info on combining long press & pan recognizers:

[Combining a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with a UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492200/combining-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-with-a-uipangesturerecognizer)

Next you'll need an efficient way of hit testing for cells in the view. Assuming you're using self.view for the gesture recognizers, try:

```
if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint location = [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *subview = [self.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
}
```

Then you can associate it with a cell in your table view and trigger the selection:

```
if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)subview];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

This is all purely hypothetical, but it should be a straightforward way of approaching this problem. The challenge will be configuring the gesture recognizers to work together with your table view.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi TTillage, i married the code specified above with that found in the linked post and while i can get the pan gesture delegate to fire after a longhold, it only fires on one cell and doesn't transfer over to the next.

Comment: If you want to post the relevant code snippets I'd be happy to take and look and see if anything seems out of place.