# Simultaneous UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I've added the following two UIGestureRecognizers to got triggered on LongPress and Pan Gestures.

```
_selectionRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectionHasBeenRecognized:)];

_dragRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragDropGestureHasBeenRecognized:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_selectionRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_dragRecognizer];
```

Each of the two recognizers work fine in single use, but it is not possible to pan directly after the LongPress gesture without releasing my finger and touch again.

Is it possible to combine both recognizers so both gestures could be done simultaneously?

Comment: Do these answers address your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492200/combining-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-with-a-uipangesturerecognizer

Comment: @jtbandes: It seems to address my question. I'll give it a try, thanks :)